# Hibernate doesn't add auto_increment

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, h2, spring-boot-test

I'm running into an issue when running my SpringBootTests.

The tests are using an H2 database, so they recreate the schema every time they run. **For one of my entities, Hibernate doesn't add `auto_increment` to the `id` column.**

I can't find any relevant differences between the failing entity (`Payment`) and others that work correctly (e.g. `Invoice`). They all have the following annotations on the `id` field:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
```

I set `spring.jpa.show-sql=true`, and this is what I see:

- The `Payment` entity shows `create table payment (id bigint not null,`
- The `Invoice` entity shows `create table invoice (id bigint not null
  auto_increment,`

In fact, I tried copying the `Payment` class to `Payment2`, and `Payment2` did not have the issue:

- The `Payment` entity shows `create table payment (id bigint not null,`
- The `Payment2` entity shows `create table invoice (id bigint not null
  auto_increment,`

Given this, I believe I should be looking for an overriding configuration that's *not* in the `Payment` class, but that somehow removes `auto_increment` from just that one class. 
**Does anyone know what could be causing this?**

These are the versions of the libraries involved:

- Spring Boot version 2.1.8
- Hibernate 5.3.11
- H2 Database 1.4.200

Comment: Have you try (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

Comment: check your id column in your databse.  is it auto increament?

Comment: @tashi AUTO breaks when running with MySQL (H2 is just for tests). Also, every possibly related answer out there says to move away from AUTO to IDENTITIY.

Comment: @GolamMazidsajib As I said in the question: "The tests are using an H2 database, so they recreate the schema every time they run." There is no DB with a column that has to match my code.

Comment: @tashi Didn't mean to just dismiss your comment. I tried changing it just to see if it would make a difference. It did not; AUTO vs IDENTITY doesn't appear to affect this.

Comment: Show your full payment class

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. This assumption was correct:

> I should be looking for an overriding configuration that's not in the `Payment` class, but that somehow removes `auto_increment` from just that one class.

Turned out that a colleague had added a "light" read-only version of the `Payment` entity called `PaymentLight`. It read from the same `payment` table but without any of the joins. The `id` field in the `PaymentLight` class did not have the `@GeneratedValue` annotation.

I haven't checked this, but I assume Hibernate merged the two entities (the light class was a subset anyway) and used the `@GeneratedValue` configuration from one of them (likely alphabetical order).